# App Script Google sheets sender email id change after the ownership transfer

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, automation, sourceforge-appscript, py-appscript

How to change the sender of the email after the ownership transfer of the app script code in google sheets?

I have transferred the ownership of a **Google Sheets App Script code**, which sends **emails** to relevant stakeholders upon certain events.

code:

```
function sendEmailByRow(row)  
{
   var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Projects").getRange(row,1,row,45).getValues();  
   var row_values = values[0];
   var candidate_email = composeCandidateEmail(row_values);  // to staff
 
   MailApp.sendEmail(
      candidate_email.email,
      candidate_email.cc,
      candidate_email.subject,
      candidate_email.message
   );  //on saying yes it will send an email                  
}
```

I have tried running the code from my id as well but didn't work. The code contains no block where the sender's mail id is mentioned. *(MailApp function is used)*

I want the email to go from my Email Id.